# Problem filtering orders from user who owns the product - Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Friends, I have an order table, where I record the orders made by a user. The table has these fields:

**id, quantity, product_id, user_id**

In this way, the user can buy his product and consult his history. The problem is that I want to do this on the side of the company that registered the product. I want to filter by product_id only for the user who owns the product.

My OrdersTable.php

```
.
.
    $this->belongsTo('Products', [
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
    }
```

My method is below. Note that I enter the id manually as an example. The idea is to capture this information from the user who is logged in. I appreciate if anyone can review or comment. I don't know how to solve this detail!

```
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = ['contain' => ['Users','Products']];
        $query = $this->Orders->find('all')->where(['Orders.product_id' => 76]);

        $this->set('orders', $this->paginate($query));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['order']);
    }
```

Comment: What method are you using for authentication? The old component or the new plugin? Look at the documentation for that for how to get the logged in user, and add that to your `where` clause.

Comment: This I do this way:  $this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('Auth.User.id'). However I need to filter by product_id to display the products that were selected and that belong to the user who registered. The result of the code I entered returns the user id.

Comment: Your description of what you are trying to do can be interpreted in many different ways, it's very hard to figure what exactly you mean / what exactly the problem is that you're experiencing. It would probably help if you could provide an example of what you want the final query to look like, or an example of what is in your database , and the dataset that you want to retrieve.

Comment: My order table has the fields: id, quantity, product_id, user_id. When the customer buys a product, he can retrieve the history because his id is saved. I am trying to retrieve the information of the product that was chosen and display it to the user (company) that registered it.

Comment: I hope you have managed to understand. When I enter an id manually like this: $ this-> Orders-> find ('all') -> where (['Orders.product_id' => 76]); I can filter the product with the id 76. I don't know what to put in place of the 76 so that this is identified for the user who is logged in.

Comment: Sorry, no, it's all very ambiguous to me. "_so that this is identified for the user who is logged in_" I have no idea what that means exactly. Maybe you want to find all products for a specific user, maybe you want to find only specific products and additionally filter those by a specific user, maybe something totally different, I can't really tell. There seems to be a bit of language barrier here (no offense, this isn't ment as a snide), hence why I was suggesting showing what you're looking for with example data.

Comment: If you know what the final SQL query should look like, that would also help to better understand the problem that you're possibly having with the query builder.

Comment: I think you're just looking for `->where(['Orders.user_id' =>  $this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('Auth.User.id')])`?

Comment: I don't really know the language very much. Imagine a platform where multiple companies can sell their products. When purchasing a product, you can access your history of what was purchased. This I managed to do. The company that sold the product can also access its products that were sold. The problem is precisely this, I need to create a filter considering that there are several companies that have products. I need to identify if any orders were saved in the database containing product_id for the company that is logged on the platform.

Comment: Company A has products with id equal to 1.2 and 3. Company B has a product with id equal to 4. If company A logs in to the system, it will be able to filter orders with product_id equal to 1.2 and 3. Orders with product_id equal to 4 do not enter the history of company A.

Comment: i wish to know who initiates order(customer?). who has the product(company?). please mention other tables relationship(if any). i am unable understand the business process here.

Comment: I have the user table. I separate the customer and the company through the group_id field. the customer starts the process. He buys a product and his id is saved in the user_id. The company identifies the purchase of the product. the product id is saved in the order table (product_id). On the company side, I need to filter if the product she registered was saved in the order table.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your attention. I decided this way:

```
        $query = $this->Orders->find();
        $query->contain('Products', function ($q) {
            return $q->where(['Products.user_id' => $this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('Auth.User.id')]);
        });
```